# Java - Not compiling error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm doing the code for a shop and this part is to allow the staff to add a phone to existing stock. I cant figure out what the problem is as it wont compile and says "incompatible types", it marks the part [ name= "  "; 
                    type="  ";
                     colour=" ";]

Here's the part of the driver class that it is in:

```
      //add new phone to stock
public void addPhone( ) {

     Phone phone = new Phone ( itemsId, brand, price, name, type, colour);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String itemsId; 
    String brand;
    double price;
    String name;
    String type;
    String colour;


    for (int counter=0; counter< 1; counter ++)
    {
        itemsId= "  ";
        brand="     ";
        price= 
        name= "  ";
        type="  ";
        colour=" ";

        System.out.println("Enter itemsID:   ");
        itemsId= scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter brand:     ");
        brand= scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter price:     ");
        price= scan.nextdouble();

        System.out.println("Enter name:      ");
        name= scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter type:       ");
        type= scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter colour:     ");
        colour= scan.nextLine();

    }
    phoneList.add(phone);

}
```

Comment: Look at this line `price= `

Comment: its compiling but the lines after wont

Comment: At that line, you are saying `price=name="  "`, so you are trying to assign a string to a double.

Comment: Oh ok but how should i code it, as price is a double ?

Comment: Put a double after price instead of nothing? `price = 5.0;` or whatever.

Comment: System.out.println("Enter price: "); price= scan.nextdouble(); <--- is this line correct ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java statements are semi-colon terminated. Then

```
price= 
name= "  ";
```

is parsed as `price = (name = "  ")`. However, a `String` (type/result of the name assignment expression) is incompatible with a `double` (the type of the price variable) as they are "incompatible types".

So first step is to fix how the code is parsed

```
price= <put something useful here>;
name= "  ";
```

While this will "fix" the immediate type error, the program will still not compile (due to unassigned local variables and incorrect method names) and, if it did compile, would not produce the correct results when more than one phone number is to be entered - keep reading.

---

Now, as far as the overall program: *don't* assign these "dummy values" and *don't* use the variables before they have meaningful values.

Consider this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int counter = 0; counter < 1; counter++)
{
    // We don't need to assign defaults because these
    // variables will be assigned useful values before
    // they are used.
    double price;
    String name;
    // (other variables removed for simplicity)

    System.out.println("Enter price:     ");
    // Java is case-sensitive, make sure to use correct case.
    // The original "nextdouble" was incorrect.
    price = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter name:      ");
    name = scan.nextLine();

    // NOW use variables - AFTER they have useful values
    Phone phone = new Phone (.., .., price, name, .., ..);

    // Add new phone entry each loop,
    // not once at the end of all (1) loops.
    phoneList.add(phone);
}
```

Comment: the line ---> price= scan.nextdouble(); its not right

Comment: @user3537296 You're welcome. The compiler is right about the errors, so remember to patiently listen to it - and fix/address one error at a time.

Answer (score 6):

You should assign a value to `price`.

```
price = 0.0;
name = " ";
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
price = 
name = " ";
```

is the same code as

```
price = name = " ";
```

which means that you're assigning String value to the double - these types are incompatible;
Either, remove "price = " line or add value to the right of "price = " line:

```
price = 0;
name = " ";
```